# Por que no se cambia la propiedad CSS en Menu en Bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery

estoy intentando de que cambie la propiedad active de la etiqueta a en mi menú, pero cuando doy click me cambia la propiedad pero automáticamente vuelve todo como estaba, El proyecto lo estoy realizando en Symfony y plantillas twig. Y quisiera agregarle el cambio de color en el menu para evitar que se pierdan en el sistema.  les dejo el código como esta en el proyecto.

```
nav class="mt-2">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
    <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
         with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
    <li class="nav-item menu-open">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
            <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
            <p>
                Procesos
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
            </p>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview" id="menu">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('archivo_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Planificación</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('medicion_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Medición y Análisis</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('investigacion_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Investigación y Desarrollo</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('compras_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Compras</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('produccion_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Producción de Inyectables</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('yogurt_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Producción de Yogurt</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{ path('capitalh_index') }}" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                    <p>Capital Humano</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Este es el Script

```
 $('li a').click(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('ul').find('li.active,a.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.parent().addClass('active');

    });
```

En espera de alguna solución

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que en el siguiente fragmento retiras la clase:

```
$this.closest('ul').find('li.active,a.active').removeClass('active');
```

Pero al momento la vuelves a añadir con:

```
$this.addClass('active');
$this.parent().addClass('active');
```

Al hacer el *removeClass* del *ul* mas cercano lo estas volviendo a poner con el *parent addClass*.

Espero haberte resuelto la duda!